# How to use Travis CI environment variables + .sh script for auto deployment to Github Pages?

Tags: shell, unix, continuous-integration, travis-ci, github-pages

## UPDATE: This is working, but needs fine-tuning (see below)

> **Repo Link:** https://github.com/oneezy/sweet-element 
>   **Travis CI Link:** https://travis-ci.org/oneezy/sweet-element

## Automation: Travis CI + Github Pages

To explain in more detail what my goals are, I'm trying to simplify my Github + Travis CI workflow w/ 2 environment variables `GH_TOKEN` + `GH_REF` stored in a `.travis.yml` and an executable `gpages_build.sh` shell script that's used to auto deploy a demo & docs to Github pages `on_success:` when I `git push` from command line. I want to create my `.travis.yml` in such a way that it never has to be manually edited so that it's *smart* enough to generate the values it needs for `GH_REF` depending on information that already exists (more details below).

I've followed 2 blog posts that have gotten me to the point I'm at now:

**Tutorial 1:** [How to build Polymer components with Github and Travis CI](https://medium.com/collaborne-engineering/how-to-build-polymer-components-with-github-and-travis-67683ef8bf0d#.lbmv46euv)

**Tutorial 2:** [Automatic github pages deployment for Polymer elements with Travis CI](https://zisismaras.me/polymer/2015/12/02/automatic-github-pages-for-polymer-elements-with-travis-ci.html)

---

## Current Working Setup ✔

**✔** Create *"Personal Access Token"* from Github

**✔** Use `travis encrypt` command to add `GH_TOKEN` environment variable to `.travis.yml`

**✔** Add `GH_REF: github.com/oneezy/sweet-element` environment variable

**✔** Use `.travis.yml` to set everything else up

**✔** Use `gpages_build.sh` to make auto deployment to Github Pages

**✔** Make `gpages_build.sh` executable w/ `git update-index --chmod=+x gpages_build.sh`

**✔** `git push` and watch it all come together

---

## The Problem ✖

**✖** Manually writing `GH_REF` value in `.travis.yml` is repetitive/ tedious

**✖** Manually writing `git update-index --chmod=+x gpages_build.sh` is repetitive/ tedious

---

## Possible Solutions & Questions ?

**?** Can I dynamically generate `GH_REF` value w/ information that already exists?

**?** Can I pull information from `bower.json` or `package.json` to generate `GH_REF` value?

**?** Can I pull information from `git config` to generate `GH_REF` value?

**?** Does Travis CI provide any variables that can be used instead of `GH_REF`?

**?** How can I make the `gpages_build.sh` script executable for all projects?

**?** Can I execute the `gpages_build.sh` script from an entire different repo?

**?** Can I make the `gpages_build.sh` script executable from the `.travis.yml`?

---

## The Codes...

**.travis.yml [(Github Link)](https://github.com/oneezy/sweet-element/blob/master/.travis.yml)**

```
language: node_js
node_js: stable
sudo: required
dist: trusty
addons:
  firefox: latest
  apt:
    sources:
    - google-chrome
    packages:
    - google-chrome-stable

install:
- npm install -g bower polymer-cli
- npm install
- bower install

script:
- xvfb-run polymer test

after_success:
- if [ "$TRAVIS_BRANCH" = "master" ]; then 
  ./gpages_build.sh oneezy sweet-element "Justin O'Neill'" justin@oneezy.com; fi

env:
  global:
    - GH_REF: github.com/oneezy/sweet-element
    - secure: 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
```

**gpages_build.sh [(Github Link)](https://github.com/oneezy/sweet-element/blob/master/gpages_build.sh)**

```
#
# Modified to work with Travis CI automated builds
# Original license follows
#
# @license
# Copyright (c) 2014 The Polymer Project Authors. All rights reserved.
# This code may only be used under the BSD style license found at http://polymer.github.io/LICENSE.txt
# The complete set of authors may be found at http://polymer.github.io/AUTHORS.txt
# The complete set of contributors may be found at http://polymer.github.io/CONTRIBUTORS.txt
# Code distributed by Google as part of the polymer project is also
# subject to an additional IP rights grant found at http://polymer.github.io/PATENTS.txt
#

# This script pushes a demo-friendly version of your element and its
# dependencies to gh-pages.

# usage gp Polymer core-item [branch]
# Run in a clean directory passing in a GitHub org and repo name
org=$1
repo=$2
name=$3
email=$4
branch=${5:-"master"} # default to master when branch isn't specified

mkdir temp && cd temp

# make folder (same as input, no checking!)
mkdir $repo
git clone "https://${GH_TOKEN}@${GH_REF}" --single-branch

# switch to gh-pages branch
pushd $repo >/dev/null
git checkout --orphan gh-pages

# remove all content
git rm -rf -q .

# use bower to install runtime deployment
bower cache clean $repo # ensure we're getting the latest from the desired branch.
git show ${branch}:bower.json > bower.json
echo "{
  \"directory\": \"components\"
}
" > .bowerrc
bower install
bower install $org/$repo#$branch
git checkout ${branch} -- demo
rm -rf components/$repo/demo
mv demo components/$repo/

# redirect by default to the component folder
echo "<META http-equiv="refresh" content=\"0;URL=components/$repo/\">" >index.html

git config user.name $name
git config user.email $email

# send it all to github
git add -A .
git commit -am 'Deploy to GitHub Pages'
git push --force --quiet -u "https://${GH_TOKEN}@${GH_REF}" gh-pages > /dev/null 2>&1

popd >/dev/null
```

Comment: `GH_REF` could be a separate branch instead. If you always deploy from a stable branch, the SHA shouldn't matter.

Comment: @osowskit , I'm not sure I understand. The `GH_REF` variable will always equal `github.com/user/repo`. I'm trying to see if it's possible to dynamically generate this `GH_REF` value w/ information that already exists so that I never have to edit the`.travis.yml`. For example, `github.com` will never change, the `user` will always be my Github name, `oneezy` which is already stored in `git` as my `git config --global name`, and the `repo`, in this case `sweet-element` will be the piece that changes most often, and this value will always be stored in either a `bower.json` or `package.json` file.

Comment: Can your script use the `TRAVIS_REPO_SLUG` mentioned [here](https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/environment-variables/#Default-Environment-Variables)

Comment: Ahhhh, this is might be the exact thing I'm looking for! I'll test and report back

Comment: They have also added the ability to [publish from source](https://github.com/blog/2228-simpler-github-pages-publishing) `/docs`

Comment: I managed to do EVERYTHING that I wanted! :) ... Thanks a lot for the guidance! Will post up results tomorrow... Time for some much needed rest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to do **EVERYTHING** I wanted to.

---

## My Goals

- Automating `GH_REF` value in `gpages_build.sh` script w/ the `TRAVIS_REPO_SLUG` *(thanks for the tip @osowskit !)*
- Writing `git update-index --chmod=+x gpages_build.sh` once and storing it into it's own repo...when needing it, just `bower install` it!

---

## ✔ The Process

Here's my exact approach I took for creating and testing `<custom-elements>` w/ **Travis CI** and auto deploying to **Github Pages** after a successful build.

**gpages_build.sh (script):**

1. In order to move away from having to make my script executable inside every project w/ the `git update-index --chmod=+x gpages_build.sh` command, I needed to centralize this process inside one handy Github repo *([oneezy/build-tools](https://github.com/oneezy/build-tools))*. The benefits of this are:

   - Only having to make the script executable once
   - Being able to update the script as needed in one place (not every repo)
   - Ensuring that when others clone the project, they'll always have the *executable* file
2. In order to make the `GH_REF` variable automatic and not have to write it out each time, Travis CI gives us the `TRAVIS_REPO_SLUG` variable, which is basically `username/repo` for whatever Github Repository you're working in. You write it out like this: `GH_REF="github.com/${TRAVIS_REPO_SLUG}"`

```

```
# This script pushes a demo-friendly version of your element and its
# dependencies to gh-pages.

# usage gp Polymer core-item [branch]
# Run in a clean directory passing in a GitHub org and repo name

GH_REF="github.com/${TRAVIS_REPO_SLUG}"

org=`echo ${TRAVIS_REPO_SLUG} | cut -f 1 -d /`
repo=`echo ${TRAVIS_REPO_SLUG} | cut -f 2 -d /`

name="Travis CI"
email="builds@oneezy.com"
branch=${3:-"master"} # default to master when branch isn't specified

mkdir temp && cd temp

# make folder (same as input, no checking!)
mkdir $repo
git clone "https://${GH_TOKEN}@${GH_REF}" --single-branch

# switch to gh-pages branch
pushd $repo >/dev/null
git checkout --orphan gh-pages

# remove all content
git rm -rf -q .

# use bower to install runtime deployment
bower cache clean $repo # ensure we're getting the latest from the desired branch.
git show ${branch}:bower.json > bower.json
echo "{
  \"directory\": \"components\"
}
" > .bowerrc
bower install
bower install $org/$repo#$branch
git checkout ${branch} -- demo
rm -rf components/$repo/demo
mv demo components/$repo/

# redirect by default to the component folder
echo "<META http-equiv="refresh" content=\"0;URL=components/$repo/\">" >index.html

git config user.name $name
git config user.email $email

# send it all to github
git add -A .
git commit -am 'Deploy to GitHub Pages'
git push --force --quiet -u "https://${GH_TOKEN}@${GH_REF}" gh-pages > /dev/null 2>&1

popd >/dev/null
```

```

**Travis.yml Configuration:**

1. One *GOTCHA* that was throwing me off here was the `GH_TOKEN` variable, which is the *[Personal Access Token](https://github.com/settings/tokens)* you need from Github for read/write ability to your repositories. Due to the power this token has, I needed to encrypt it w/ the [Travis CLI](https://github.com/travis-ci/travis.rb#readme) *(Travis Command Line Tool)*. `travis encrypt GH_TOKEN=********* --add`, which will automatically add the encrypted variable to your `.travis.yml` file. I was under the impression that I could use the same **encrypted** `GH_TOKEN` for every repo, but I found out the hard way that's not the case. When you encrypt anything w/ Travis, it appears that you're essentially tieing that encryption to the repository you're in, E.G.: you must `travis encrypt GH_TOKEN=********* --add` inside every repository. One possible workaround would be to configure an alias/ command inside a `config` file w/ this information stored inside, but I haven't yet explored the theory.
2. The next thing to do is `bower install -s gpages_build.sh` script and run it from `.travis.yml` w/ `./bower_components/build-tools/gpages_build.sh`. This will automatically pull the script from our `build-tools` repo and run it.

```

```
language: node_js
node_js: stable
sudo: required
dist: trusty

addons:
  firefox: latest
  apt:
    sources:
    - google-chrome
    packages:
    - google-chrome-stable

cache:
  directories:
  - node_modules
  - "$HOME/.cache/bower"

install:
- npm install -g bower polymer-cli
- npm install
- bower install

script:
- xvfb-run polymer test

after_success:
- if [ ${TRAVIS_PULL_REQUEST} = "false" ] && [ "$TRAVIS_BRANCH" = "master" ]; then
  bower install -s oneezy/build-tools && ./bower_components/build-tools/gpages_build.sh;
  fi

# DO EVERY TIME: 
# travis encrypt GH_TOKEN=**************** --add  
# env:
#   global:
#     secure: ZwNuFN1cryC5dff4c3a1qePkoRZoug+HDiN55dFATTt7Opk20C8SgO+RGEWqYWelFkUN2jhAyoJ91GFMxOyYqbqZP+mQfBaFWgBZoKIcGcDur5in4z6ZaWfw65X03K0HIaaKaunpO4C1d/d++zMhqvudhaJ4JgXJXts5cUdmXGxCIEhKE+mH5d76VK4fbpyrtpewllqHeaiIE88oFZ0L8xQP8K7SUXukvVmE1Re0Kl0UjXjsdSUftcj+gnOcBxqGjVlSjQ9Bk0zmP+2nHYo8Gx=
```

```

## And voila!

Comment: I am trying to use your approach. Unfortunately it seems that the bower command is not found inside the script: `./gh-pages.sh: line 30: ./node_modules/.bin/bower: No such file or directory`. Any hints?

Comment: Found it: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56882350/travis-executing-bower-in-sh-script-fails

Answer (score 2):

> I'm trying to simplify my Github + Travis CI workflow w/ 2 environment variables `GH_TOKEN` + `GH_REF` stored in `.travis.yml` ... used by

```
git clone "https://${GH_TOKEN}@${GH_REF}" --single-branch
```

Your script can use the `TRAVIS_REPO_SLUG` environment variable referenced in [the documentation](https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/environment-variables/#Default-Environment-Variables)