# Travis - Executing bower in sh script fails

Tags: travis-ci, bower

I try to execute bower commands in a sh script that is run in the `after-success` phase o a travis build. I installed bower in the `install` phase:

```
install:
  - npm install -g bower

[...]

after_success:
  - if [ ${TRAVIS_PULL_REQUEST} = "false" ] && [ "$TRAVIS_BRANCH" = "master" ]; then
      ./my-script.sh;
    fi
```

Unfortunately, if I call bower in the sh script it produces the following output:

> ./my-script.sh: line 30: ./node_modules/.bin/bower: No such file or directory

I do not know how to proceed to fix the error. Any help would be greatly appreciated, thank you already!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had to call the script using

```
bash my-script.sh;
```

instead of

```
./my-script.sh;
```

Now everything is working fine.